# Socket programming in C on linux

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming

I am interested in socket programming and I learned basics of socket programming. I am doing it C on linux. Now I would like to work on some project related to socket programing. Could any body suggest from where I get help means online socket related projects?

Comment: start writing a simple app, that's the best way you will learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you see C++ as an option, you could take a look at the [network examples of the Qt framework](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/network-fortuneserver.html).

If you want to stick to C, you could take a look at the [socket support of GLib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417681/need-help-implementing-simple-socket-server-using-gioservice-glib-glib-gio).

Comment: Thats fine Taneli but Taneli where i get some real-life project on Socket programming since am good in C so i would like it to do in C.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tutorial sites:

- http://www.tenouk.com/cnlinuxsockettutorials.html
- http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm
- http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

but there are many more...

Comment: Thanks trojanfoe ,but links simply provides tutorials but i would like to do some real life projects related to socket prograaming ...

Comment: Oh see, apologies.  I would have a look through http://code.google.com and search for what you want.