# glib network connection example

Tags: c, network-programming, glib, gio

Can you advice some network connection example made with glib/gio libraries. 
There is quite a good [reference manual](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/pt02.html), but no full example even for basic things.

It will be used for simple sending and receiving files as a part of program.

Comment: I've found unanswered question on SO 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417681/need-help-implementing-simple-socket-server-using-gioservice-glib-glib-gio and try to use it as an example, but still want to find finished example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about like this?
There is similar question at [Fetch a file from web: in GTK using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622642/)

```
#include <gio/gio.h>

int main()
{
        const gchar *uri = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758770/";
        GFile *in;
        GFile *out;
        GError *error = NULL;
        gboolean ret;

        g_type_init();

        in = g_file_new_for_uri(uri);
        out = g_file_new_for_path("/tmp/a");

        ret = g_file_copy(in, out, G_FILE_COPY_OVERWRITE,
                          NULL, NULL, NULL, &error);
        if (!ret)
                g_message("%s", error->message);

        return 0;
}
```